# Binary choice model and classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, econometrics

Are there any differences between binary choice model and classification problem?

For example, binary choice model may use logistic regression, which is also an widely used approach in classification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're the same; classification is just a less cryptic way to say discrete outcome. Although, some people may consider multiple discrete outcomes a classification problem, too. So, classification may be a bigger set of models, which would then include Binary (dichotomous) outcomes and Discrete Choice Probability models (e.g., cases where you use a multinomial or multivariate model [to be more specific, suppose your dependent variable was classified into "buckets" labeled as 1 2 3 4 where order was arbitrary, this would be a discrete choice model]).

Comment: It is important to distinguish between the nature of Y (e.g., it is a continuous measure, an inherently dichotomous entity, or a classification of an underlying entity (usually information losing)) and the problem to be solved (prediction of the probability of a new Y or classification using X).  The widely applicable method of logistic regression is a risk prediction method, which has many advantages over a "classify into a binary Y" method.

Comment: I think it's important to distinguish the nature of the outcome  (i.e., whether it is continuous or discrete (and the nature of the discrete random variable)) but I would consider *most* discrete outcomes a classification problem (I say most because a Poisson RV is a discrete RV but is not a classification problem). I would consider a binary outcome, which includes the logistic probability regression model, to be a classification problem too--since it attempts to classify a realization into a 1 or 0 (even though it produces probabilities). So, I agree, but my opinion differs slightly.

Comment: I disagree sharply.  The number one goal for the vast majority of problems is to estimate Prob[Y=1], not to do a forced choice between Y=0 and Y=1.  And the entire method of maximum likelihood estimation, used to estimate the logistic regression coefficients, is based on this.

Comment: My point is that using a model that estimates Prob[Y=1|X=x] or Prob[Y=j|X=x], where you have j outcomes is tantamount to solving a classification problem. Most, if not all, classification models produce probabilities; they just yield classified outcomes based on the 0.5 threshold. So, much like the Method of Maximum Likelihood, they all produce probabilities, most users just tend to focus on the classified outcome and not the probability estimates.

Comment: I do not agree that most users focus on the classification and not the probability estimates.  A 0.5 threshold (and any other) is arbitrary and reflects a lack of incorporation of loss/utility/cost functions.

Comment: I entirely agree that a 0.5 threshold (and any other) is arbitrary, but that implies nothing about what is done in academia, versus what is done in practice. We will simply have to disagree on, apparently, everything else.

Comment: This has nothing to do with academia vs practice.  Are you familiar with credit scoring models done in finance?  Lift curves in business?

Comment: I am familiar with ROC curves in business and I do understand what you are saying about probabilities being used to estimate models. My statement is simply that any classification model provides Prob[Y=j|X=x].

Comment: I would say that a probability model provides an estimate of Prob[Y=j | X=x].  A probability is not used to estimate models.  Probability estimates come from the model's estimated parameters.  The notion of classification need not be involved, and requires specification of an additional function - the loss function.  Those who do not specify a loss (utility) function are using one implicitly without knowing it.  Probabilities can be used on their own by decision makers.